# Android Studio 0.3.2 issue in Gradle with Facebook

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio, facebook-android-sdk

When I run gradle via console with command: clean,build, installDebug everything is OK. When I try run my project in Android Studio, I have this error message:

```
Gradle: Could not copy MANIFEST.MF to '/Users/*/AndroidStudioProjects/*/libraries/facebook/build/tmp/packageDebugJar/MANIFEST.MF'.
```

What is wrong? I try change chmod but this not resolve my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution:

```
cd [PATH_TO_YOUR_PROJECT]/libraries/facebook/
rm -r packageDebugJar/
rm -r packageReleaseJar/
```

Comment: I just removed the file `MANIFEST.MF` and then reran the project which regenerated this file.  And all worked after that.